# using the HttpClient, how can I cleanly read and de-serialize an RSS feed?

Tags: c#, .net, rss, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am using [the HttpClient that is available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient).

This is the code I started with:

```
string url = "http://example.com/rssfeed.rss";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "CheesoTest");
var task = client.GetAsync(url);
try
{
    task.Wait();
    HttpResponseMessage resp = task.Result;

    var t2 = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<RSS.Feed>();
    t2.Wait();
    var result = t2.Result;
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + e1.ToString());
}
```

Problems:

1. I had to explicitly define `RSS.Feed` and decorate it with DataContract/DataMember attributes.  It sure seems like an RSS class ought to be built in. Is it?  (Maybe I just don't know about it)
2. This fails with an exception complaining about the processing instruction in the RSS feed. It's actually a stylesheet, which I don't care about. I just want the data.

The exception is:

> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Processing instructions (other than the XML declaration) and DTDs are not supported. Line 1, position 2.

The feed looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/rss.xsl"?>
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel><title>blah foo fizz bang</title>....
```

Any hints on a better way to do this?  Using HttpClient!!

I find that the documentation is a little thin.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, have you looked into WCF's SyndicationFeed?  System.ServiceModel.dll has a [SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515814.aspx) method that can deserialize a feed into a SyndicationFeed object.